# How to Fix memory leak in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, hhvm

My server is running HHVM.

Everything is working almost fine, except on thing. Because of memory leaks the Translation Cache gets filled up, and once it is almost full the HHVM can not render the pages anymore so every user only would see a blank page instead of the article.

To prvent this from happening it is necessary that all `create_function` calls get replaced by anonymous functions. 
See (for more info):

> https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4250#issuecomment-88941383

and the docs of hhvm which also say to use anonymous functions:

> http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.create-function.php

So my question now is how do I replace the create function calls which are made in the `translation.php` and the `po.php` with anonymous functions?

Comment: Well, you open the files in an editor, and rewrite the `create_function` calls manually, or you can write a script that automates the process... I don't really get what's so hard about that, unless you're not telling the whole story

Comment: What version of HHVM are you using? I believe this particular leak was fixed a while ago -- 3.9 should be new enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, either manually edit the files, or write a script that replaces all `create_function` calls and turns them into closures. Something like this should be enough to do the job:

```
$string = file_get_contents('path/to/po.php');


if (preg_match_all('/(\$.+?)create_function[^\(]*\(.*?(\'([^\']+)\'|"([^"]+)")\s*,\s*[\'"](.+?)[\'"]\);$/m', $string, $matches)) {
    $createCalls = count($matches[0]);
    $createStrings = [];//array of matches
    $replaceStrings = [];//array of new bits of code
    for ($i=0;$i<$createCalls;++$i) {
        //iterate over matches, build replace strings
        $createStrings[] = $matches[0][$i];//the full match
        $args = $matches[3][$i] ?: $matches[4][$i];//I'll explain this later on
        $replaceStrings[] = sprintf(
            '%sfunction(%s) {' . PHP_EOL . '    %s' . PHP_EOL . '};',
            $matches[1][$i],
            $args,
            $matches[5][$i]
        );
    }
    $string = str_replace($createStrings, $replaceStrings, $string);
    file_put_contents('path/to/po.php', $string);//write new contents to file
}
```

Just to show that it works [***Demo here***](https://eval.in/445093)

On the regex:

- `(\$.+?)`: match and capture the assignment: a literal `$` sign, followed by any character, non-greedy because of `?`. The match will stop when the next part of the pattern is matched
- `create_function[^\(]*\(.*?`: match `create_function` literally, then any non `(` character zero or more times (in case there's a space). Then match a literal `(`, and zero or more chars that aren't defined further down in the regex (again: this is mainly for spaces)
- `(\'([^\']+)\'|"([^"]+)")`: Either match a single quote, and anything in between that is a single quote, or a double quote, and anything in between that isn't a double quote. The entire match is grouped twice: once with the quotes, once without the quotes. Lookaround assertions could've avoided the double grouping, but this is just a regex I put together quickly, tweaking it further is something you can do if you want
- `\s*,\s*[\'"]`: zero or more spaces, a comma and zero or more spaces again, followed by a single or double quote. this matches the comma-separator between the two arguments passed to `create_function`, we don't need this bit, hence no capturing
- `(.+?)`: match and capture anything, until the rest of the pattern is matched
- `[\'"]\);$`: a single or double quote, closing bracket a semi-colon and an EOL. Put simply: the last 3 visible chars of a single line of code. The closing `");` literal of a `create_function` call. No need to capture this either, so we don't

Now we know what our `$matches` array will look like:

- `0`: the full line `$var = create_function('$arg1', 'return $arg1;');`
- `1`: The `$var =` bit (the actual assignment)
- `2`: The first argument, complete with quotes: `'$arg1'`
- `3`: The first argument, without the quotes: `$arg1`, **if the argument was delimited using single quotes**, an empty string if double quotes were used
- `4`: The first argument, if it was delimited using **double quotes**, empty string if single quotes were used
- `5`: The second argument without quotes, ie: the function body

#### More info:

The [regex101](http://regex101.com) breakdown of this regex [can be found here](https://regex101.com/r/kE4iY5/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time you invested and the detailed answer. I really appreciate it! I can use the same script for the translations.php right ?

Comment: @Salexes: Of course you can. The only thing that changes is the `file_*_contents` calls. You could just pour this snippet into a function, and pass the paths in a loop: `foreach ($paths as $path) { rewriteFile($path); };` where `$paths` is an array containing the paths to all files that need processing